# Will heat cause a silicone scraper to harden?

Tags: utensils

I like to use a flexible silicone scraper to stir my eggs in the pan when scrambling them. I know silicone is heat resistant so it won't melt, but will prolonged exposure to heat gradually cause the silicone to harden and become less flexible?

Comment: My silicone oven forms are doing fine. Still as wobly as years ago.

Comment: @Robert I wouldn't be too quick to infer anything about scrappers from it. They may have been made heat resistant on purpose in some way.

Comment: It depends on the grade of silicone I think. Not all silicone is heat tolerant.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to be sure that the scraper or spatula you are using is heat resistant and suitable for cooking.

Assuming it is, heat should not make the silicone hard over time. I have several that I have been using almost daily for over ten years. They are as flexible today as when they were new.